# IIS Config Error: This configuration section cannot be used at this path

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

Sorry if this has been asked before, i can't find an answer that works. I don't normally use windows servers or IIS so i don't know how to fix this.

I have a website/application in ASP that a client needed setting up on a temporary windows vps using iis, so i installed everything and copied the site files to the document root folder, but i'm getting this error:

```
This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".

Config File    \\?\C:\inetpub\CPS\web.config
```

This looks similar to an error Apache would report on linux and i would change the director to AllowOverride true in httpd.conf but i've got no idea how to fix that on IIS.

I don't even know where in the web.config it's talking about because all the allowOverride params in there say "allow".

Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image]

And here is the web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
    Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
    web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
    the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WebReference.webservice" value="http://192.168.1.30/webservice.asmx"/>
    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;dir=c:\TempImageFiles\;"/>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CAMSConn" connectionString="Data Source=WIN-J1AR57RKUTM\CAMS;Initial Catalog=CAMSAdmin;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=TeaPot101" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <!-- 
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.
        -->
    <httpHandlers>
      <remove path="*.asmx" verb="*" />
      <add path="*.asmx" verb="*" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        validate="false" />
      <add path="*_AppService.axd" verb="*" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        validate="false" />
      <add path="ScriptResource.axd" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        validate="false" />
      <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="480" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" >
      <assemblies>

        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
        -->
    <pages clientIDMode="AutoID">
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <!--<httphandlers>
      <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
    </httphandlers>-->
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <add value="home.aspx"/>
        <add value="download.aspx"/>
        <add value="index.aspx"/>
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <handlers>
      <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="support@cordexinstruments.com">
        <network defaultCredentials="true" host="localhost" password="TeaPot101" userName="Kylua"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The actual error page should contain the line number and the actual XML node that triggers the error. With that it is very likely to find duplicate posts on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yeh I put a location tag where it said and it produced another error. All of this is easier on Linux lol

Comment: Hope some day you learn the right way to ask questions and do research. I don't know what kind of location tag you added, but if it produced another error, then you have read something wrong, and was on the wrong track. IIS is pretty easy once you know the basics, and if you post enough details (like other questions under the same IIS tag), others can also help (but you didn't).

Comment: @LexLi well I did do research and I found no answer to the issue, I don't need to know IIS inside out, I'm a linux developer and I use apache, this is a one off. I have updated the question with more detail. It's the same config file that comes from another iis server, just doesn't like working here.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SqqM_QE_5CE The relevant settings at server level must be unlocked first. Probably on the other server you run a different version of Windows (some unlocks the settings by default), or someone unlocked that server already.

Comment: Thanks, that is a solution, but why does it do that? Why is it locked?

Comment: Allowing modules or handlers to be overridden in `web.config` raises secure risks, so Microsoft decided to lock the sections by default. I will be surprised if Linux does not do the same if it has similar settings.

Comment: @LexLi thanks, that seems to have fixed it.